# Should we have the mhchem MathJax extension enabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) have the [mhchem](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#mhchem) MathJax extension enabled, which makes it easier to write chemical species and reactions. Should this extension be enabled here? I imagine that it will be useful for some questions in [geochemistry](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geochemistry), at minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now possible describe stratospheric ozone with equations:

$$
\ce{O2 ->[\text{uv light}] 2 O}\\
\ce{O2 + O -> O3}
$$

Some helpful information:

1. [A guide on the basics of mhchem](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-format-math-and-chemistry-expressions-here).
2. Resist the urge to [overuse $\TeX$](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/overusing-tex).

Other than that... enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

List of questions that would benefit from mhchem:

- [Peak phosphorus - what are the sinks?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/415/67)
- [What would happen if we could revert $\mathrm{CO}_2$ production but took it too far?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/888/67)
- [How were we able to measure carbon dioxide levels in earlier climates?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/34/67)
- [How does radiogenic argon-40 get into the atmosphere?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/1027/67) (features a reaction)
- [How does one create petroleum/crude oil for future generations?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2824/87)
- [What is the mechanism behind changes in oxidation state (of iron, for example) as magma rises?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2496/87)
- [What makes the conditions at the core/mantle boundary ideal for aluminum to combine with other elements besides oxygen?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2478/87)
- [What is it about ancient craton geology that results in associated kimberlite pipes containing economic diamond deposits?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2509/725)
- [What's the difference between the upper & lower mantle?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/335/725) (features a reaction)

(Please edit this answer with any other questions that would benefit from mhchem.)

Comment: Examples are good.  It would also be helpful to have examples where chemical reactions (more than just naming molecules) being written would improve the posts.  Once we get a few more examples I'll make sure a CM sees this.