# Switch the "MathJax help" link on /ask to our own MathJax guidelines

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, mathjax

Currently, the [Ask Question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page links to [a Harvard tutorial](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) on how to use TeX/LaTeX. While this teaches people most everything they would need to know about LaTeX, we've [created our own page](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-format-math-and-chemistry-expressions-here) (based off of [a tutorial on Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88)) that identifies the most common use cases for MathJax on our site. Since this page is much easier to read and is more applicable to use of MathJax on Earth Science, could we have the "MathJax help" link point to our own, specific tutorial vs. the Harvard one?

Comment: @Shog9: If there's room to add an extra link for MathJax help, SE Mathematics [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) has its own MathJax reference & guide which has aspects of MathJax not mentioned on the Chemistry site. I think a link to both would be useful.

Comment: Just link to it from your own guide here, @Fred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, done.

[image]